# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY(confilct with table not included in context build)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am getting the following error. Could you please help me? In addition i want to mention that the FISCALYEAR table is not selected in my EF CORE POWER TOOLS the tool that i use to build my DBContext. It fails when i call SaveChanges().

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "bzCnR1258". The conflict occurred in database "Db", table "dbo.FISCALYEAR".
> The statement has been terminated.

```
    public Task<bool> InsertTransactionToTrades(Transaction transaction)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        Trades trade = new Trades
        {
            invo = transaction.Invo,
            custid = transaction.CustomerId,
            defbraid = transaction.Defbraid,
            braid = transaction.Braid,
            date = date,
            trnstypeid = transaction.Trnstypeid,
            docserid = transaction.Docserid
        };

        _context.Cmptrades.Add(cmptrade);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return _context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
```

Comment: Look into your database what the constaint means. The error comes from the database so its not relevant how you defined the EF side. Its the Database that does not like what you send to it.

Comment: The FISCALYEAR is a KEY which means that there only can be one entry with same year AND the key must be included. Your transaction does not have a FISCALYEAR.

Comment: Add some logging to see the SQL statement that is generated.  I expect the FK column to the FiscalYear table is null in the Insert VALUES clause, or maybe contains a placeholder default which does not exist in the FiscalYear table.  It is not a good idea to have an EF table depend on a non-EF table.